# How to find the missing inodes?

Tags: openvz, linode, df, du

`df -i` reports

```
Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/simfs     300000 250697 49303   84% /
```

so around 250K inodes in use.

`du -shx --inodes /` reports 70K

to be sure no inodes was hidden behind mounts, i tested

```
mkdir /mnt/test/
mount --bind / /mnt/test/
du -shx --inodes /mnt/test/
```

That also report 70K.

So where is the rest of them, missing around 180K (250%).

What more tests can I do? Do I need to ask the OpenVZ-support? if so, what to ask?

in case its useful, `mount` reports

> /vz/private/1210881 on / type simfs (rw,relatime,usrquota,grpquota)

Answer (score 2):

You have an OpenVZ "server" which isn't really a true virtual machine - it's a container. With OpenVZ, host resources are shared among all of the containers, and are controlled by the same OS kernel. The kernel enforces some controls over what resources the containerized processes are able to see and which they aren't. Unfortunately in many cases, the way in which they do this is sub-optimal from a user's point of view.

OpenVZ is notorious for things like this - users (like yourself) *think* they have a proper virtual machine and assume that they can interact with it as they would a standard system, and are frequently confused when statistics like this don't line up with what they expect.

I'm not familiar enough with OpenVZ to say authoritatively if what you're seeing is an artifact of the OpenVZ container, but I have a fairly high confidence that this is actually the case. For this reason, and many, many others, I would recommend switching to a provider that uses a proper virtualization technology (KVM is the obvious choice here, but there are also plenty of solid providers that use Xen).